# Count of an XML child node's attribute values using Python 3.x

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I am trying to get a count of an element's (GRADE) values for a given node (SCHOOL) (based on the example below, the result would be: GR12=2, GR10=1, GR9=4, GR11=1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:SchoolUpload xmlns:ns1="http://abcsite.ca">
<ns1:School>
        <ns1:SchoolID>123456</ns1:SchoolID>
        <ns1:Students>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:ID>1</ns1:ID><ns1:Grade>GR12</ns1:Grade><ns1:Name>A. Green</ns1:Name>
            </ns1:Student>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:ID>2</ns1:ID><Grade>GR9</ns1:Grade><ns1:Name>B. Green</ns1:Name>
            </ns1:Student>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:ID>3</ns1:ID><Grade>GR12</ns1:Grade><ns1:Name>A. Blue</ns1:Name>
            </ns1:Student>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:ID>4</ns1:ID><Grade>GR9</ns1:Grade><ns1:Name>B. Blue</ns1:Name>
            </ns1:Student>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:ID>5</ns1:ID><Grade>GR11</ns1:Grade><ns1:Name>C. Blue</ns1:Name>
            </ns1:Student>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:ID>6</ns1:ID><Grade>GR9</ns1:Grade><ns1:Name>A. Redd</ns1:Name>
            </ns1:Student>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:ID>7</ns1:ID><Grade>GR9</ns1:Grade><ns1:Name>B. Redd</ns1:Name>
            </ns1:Student>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:ID>8</ns1:ID><ns1:Grade>GR10</ns1:Grade><ns1:Name>C. Redd</ns1:Name>
            </ns1:Student>
        </ns1:Students>
    <ns1:School>
</ns1:SchoolUpload>
```

My solution iterates through each SCHOOL, searches on/creates a list for each GRADE attribute value, and then uses the **len()** function to obtain the element count for each GRADE list:

```
school_list = root.findall('.//{http://abcsite.ca}School') #Get list of schools
for school in school_list: 
    gr9 = school.findall("{http://abcsite.ca}Students/Student/*[@{http://abcsite.ca}Grade='GR9']")
    gr10 = school.findall("{http://abcsite.ca}Students/Student/*[@{http://abcsite.ca}Grade='GR10']")
    gr11 = school.findall("{http://abcsite.ca}Students/Student/*[@{http://abcsite.ca}Grade='GR11']")
    gr12 = school.findall("{http://abcsite.ca}Students/Student/*[@{http://abcsite.ca}Grade='GR12']")
    print(len(gr9))
    print(len(gr10))
    print(len(gr11))
    print(len(gr12))
```

However, the **school.findall()** function call does not find the specified attribute value and therefore does not return a list.  I'm just learning Python (via the https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html site)
and I've been trying different ideas all day and I think this will work, but I can't figure it out.  Any suggestions/help would be very much appreciated (also, if there's a more elegant solution, I'm all ears).

---EDIT: code revised with suggestion in comment below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main():
    ns = { 'ns1' : '{http://ontario.ca}' }
    school_file = 'c://Users/dperry2/Desktop/python/schools.XML'
    tree = ET.parse(school_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    #//I attempted to use the namespace technique with the school list(below), and although it doesn't error, it didn't return anything; school_list was empty?!?!?
    #school_list = root.findall('.//ns1:School') #, ns) 
    school_list = root.findall('.//{http://ontario.ca}School') 
    for school in school_list: 
        gr9 = school.findall("ns1:Students/ns1:Student/ns1:Grade[.='GR9']", ns)
        print(len(gr9))     
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grade` is an XML element, not attribute. In XPath, `@` is used to reference [XML attribute](http://www.xmlfiles.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) while you're not reading any XML attribute here :

```
ns = { 'ns1' : 'http://abcsite.ca' }
school_list = root.findall('.//ns1:School', namespaces=ns) #Get list of schools
for school in school_list: 
    gr9 = school.findall("ns1:Students/ns1:Student[ns1:Grade='GR9']/ns1:Grade", namespaces=ns)
    ....
    print len(gr9)
    ....
```

Since you're referencing prefixed elements many times in the code, it will be more convenient to use dictionary, as demonstrated above. Using `lxml` you can use a more idiomatic XPath, which isn't supported by `xml.etree`, for `xml.etree` only supports limited subset of XPath 1.0 :

```
gr9 = school.findall("ns1:Students/ns1:Student/ns1:Grade[.='GR9']", namespaces=ns)
```

Notice that `.` is a reference to current context node, which in the case above is `ns1:Grade` element.

Comment: Hi Har07.  Thanks again for taking the time to look at this question.  I understand the concept for using a dictionary for the namespace (that's pretty cool).  I was unsuccessful trying the namespace technique; in the first instance (creation of school_list) it didn't return anything (school_list  was empty) and in the second instance (creation of gr9) I got an error ("SyntaxError: invalid predicate").  I'll edit my original post to include the code as it currently is and if you wouldn't mind having a look maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @DaveP. You should check your code against the 1st snippet in this answer again, look more closely, they currently are different! And regarding XPath used to find `gr9`, you're not supposed to use that version of XPath expression *unless you're using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)* (your `import` statement suggested otherwise)

Comment: No no no.. my suggestion has nothing to do with programming capability, just a plain spot the difference kinda game :)  You just need to find differences between your code and the linked demo to start with.. then the reason why it worked/didn't might become obvious

Comment: To get you started, the first difference is in the dictionary value, it shouldn't contain curly braces..

Comment: Actually, I have one quick question if you don't mind.  I'm just curious why in your solution, you reference (...,' namespaces=ns') when it works by just using '(..., ns)'?  Is there an advantage to explicitly stating 'namespaces'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139274/discussion-between-dave-p-and-har07).